# Previously defined BLE services persist even after being "removed"

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using BLE to send data from an Arduino Nano 33 BLE to an Android mobile phone. I have successfully been transmitting data using custom services and characteristics. However, I have recently tried to reduced the number of characteristics that I am using and have noticed that even after changing the Arduino source code where I define each characteristic, previously defined characteristics continue to be found by my Android application and other applications like nRF Connect.

I have defined my services and characteristics using the Arduino code below. After commenting out a selection of characteristics and re-compiling, they continue to be found by other central devices.

```
const char* uuidOfService = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
const char* uuidOfRxChar = "00001142-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
const char* uuidOfTxChar = "00001143-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
//const char* uuidOfaccXChar = "00001144-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
//const char* uuidOfaccYChar = "00001145-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
//const char* uuidOfaccZChar = "00001146-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
const char* uuidOfAccChar = "00001144-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

BLEService dataService(uuidOfService);
BLECharacteristic rxChar(uuidOfRxChar, BLEWriteWithoutResponse | BLEWrite, BLE_BUFFER_SIZE);
BLECharacteristic txChar(uuidOfTxChar, BLERead | BLENotify | BLEBroadcast, BLE_BUFFER_SIZE);
//BLEFloatCharacteristic accXChar(uuidOfaccXChar, BLERead | BLENotify | BLEBroadcast);
//BLEFloatCharacteristic accYChar(uuidOfaccYChar, BLERead | BLENotify | BLEBroadcast);
//BLEFloatCharacteristic accZChar(uuidOfaccZChar, BLERead | BLENotify | BLEBroadcast);
BLECharacteristic accChar(uuidOfAccChar, BLERead | BLENotify | BLEBroadcast, BLE_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Is there some property of characteristic UUIDs that continue to be associated with a service even after being removed from the code?

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: Does the following help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50739085/7721752 . You can also delete the device from the centrals and rediscover.

Comment: "Refresh services" in nRF Connect worked perfectly, thank you! Looks like it is due to a cached connection in Android applications.